# Google AppsScript - list return [] or undefined

Tags: javascript, list, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help with my Google AppsScript code with Sheets. Basically, I need Time2List to equal specific element that are added from RemoveDup2V1 which gets Trans2 and Time2 from the first function, RemoveDup1. The first line of code in the function, clean0, is a console.log. It returns a "[]" or "undefined". I need it to return the items in the two lists, Trans2List and Time2List. I think it is being called after the lists are assigned values, so it gets set to nothing. If you know a possible answer, thanks a lot. All help is appreciated! I have added parts of my code to help. Thanks a lot!

Variables & first 3 functions:

```
    var RemoveDupV1 = "";
    var RemoveDubVV1 = "";
    var Trans2List2 = [];
    var Trans2List = [];
    var Time2List = [];
    Trans2List2 = Trans2List.slice();
    var RemoveDupV2 = "";
    var RemoveDupV3 = "";
    var RemoveDupV4 = 0;
    var RemoveDupV5 = 0;
    var RemoveDupV6 = 0;
    
    function RemoveDup1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
      if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
        if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
          RemoveDup2V1(Trans2, Time2);
          return(Trans1);
        }else{
          return(Trans1)
        }
      }else{
        return(Trans1)
      }
    }
    
    function RDR1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
      RemoveDupV1 = RemoveDup1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
      return(RemoveDupV1)
    }
    
    function RemoveDup2V1(Trans2,Time2) {
      Trans2List.push(Trans2);
      Time2List.push(Time2);
    }
```

**clean1 function:**

```
    function clean1() {
      console.log(Trans2List);
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getRange('M:M').getDisplayValues();
      var range = [];
      var index = -1
      data.forEach(function(e, i){
        index = -1;
        if (e[0] == Trans2List[index + 1])
          if(e[1] == Time2List[index +1]) range.push("M" + (i + 1));
      });
      var newRange = [];
      for(var p = 0; p < range.length-1; p++){
        newRange.push(range[index+2]);
        index = index + 2;
      }
      sheet.getRangeList(newRange).clearContent();
    }
```

Comment: `Trans2List2` is created as an Empty Array ... and never changed (or even used) - `Trans2List` is empty when you `Trans2List.slice()` so it makes sense that `Trans2List2` is `[]` ... can't see how it can ever be `undefined` though

Comment: OMG, that was on me. But I just fixed it and now it returns [] in the log. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm guessing I need the ```Trans2List``` and ```Time2List``` to be called before they are assigned values. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: You mention `clean0` in the question, but the code has `clean1`. But neither of these functions is called by the first 3 functions. It's not clear how the two code blocks are related.

Comment: Here is a dummy sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nd1hUsOiX9eobjQzaVSQzsoWzEW7d-Fx27mHCmDeUw4/edit?usp=sharing